# PDO and SQL Express 2005 - driver not found

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, pdo

Following is what I have tried...

The code:

```
try {
    //as seen in comments on php.net
    //$mssql = new PDO('sqlsrv:host=ip;port=port;dbname=db','user','pass');
    //$mssql = new PDO('mssql:host=ip,port;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');
    //$mssql = new PDO('mssql:server=ip\SQLEXPRESS; Database=db', 'user', 'pass');

    //as seen in the SQLSRV_Help.chm
    //$mssql = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=ip; Database=db', 'user', 'pass');

    //as seen on php.net
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=ip,port;Database=db", "user", "pass");
} catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

The message: `could not find driver`

**Question1:** What is the right connection syntax?

**Question2:** Did I miss something with enabling the driver (see additional info)?

Additional Info:
The system: `Windows (Wampserver) - PHP 5.3 VC9 ThreadSafe`

Inside php.ini (after restarting servers):

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

The dll's are also in the ext/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used the ODBC - SQL Native Client driver and this works**

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=ip,port;Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;");
```